# Xamarin Form: FFImageLoading: Loading image information

Tags: image, xamarin, exif, ffimageloading

I am currently using FFImageLoading and NGraphic package. Former one use to load an image and NGraphic use to do the drawing over the image. The CachedImage from FFImageLoading will handle the image with exif orientation set. Whereas, if I load the image from NGraphics to get the original image's size, the NGraphics doesn't care the exif.

I tried to call FFImageLoading.ImageService.LoadFile().Success(). The Success is not calling.

```
FFImageLoading.ImageService.Instance.LoadFile(path).Success((FFImageLoading.Work.ImageInformation arg1, FFImageLoading.Work.LoadingResult arg2) =>
        {

            var a = arg1.OriginalHeight;
            var b = arg1.OriginalWidth;
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code only creates a task for image loading. You have to run it with some extension method as `Into`, `Preload`, etc. Eg.

```
FFImageLoading.ImageService.Instance.LoadFile(path).Success((FFImageLoading.Work.ImageInformation arg1, FFImageLoading.Work.LoadingResult arg2) =>
        {

            var a = arg1.OriginalHeight;
            var b = arg1.OriginalWidth;
        }).Preload();
```

Comment: didnt worked for me. im sure i didnt something wrong